# Loading sound file from raw folder

Tags: android, audio, resources, soundpool

I'm having trouble playing sounds with my android device, I have tried to use MediaPlayer:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);
mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { mp.release(); }
});
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(sound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        mp1.start();
    }
});
```

Which got the error:

```
11-25 00:16:24.803: E/AudioFlinger(134): no more track names available
11-25 00:16:24.803: E/AudioTrack(134): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
11-25 00:16:24.803: E/AudioSink(134): Unable to create audio track
11-25 00:16:24.803: E/MediaPlayer(2538): error (-19, 0)
11-25 00:16:24.813: E/MediaPlayer(2538): Error (-19,0)
```

I also tried using SoundPool:

```
final SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
final int sound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.beep1, 1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(sound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        mp1.start();
    }
});
```

Which has similar output:

```
11-25 00:29:12.163: E/AudioFlinger(134): no more track names available
11-25 00:29:12.163: E/AudioTrack(3355): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
11-25 00:29:12.163: E/SoundPool(3355): Error creating AudioTrack
```

Am I doing anything wrong with specifying the resouce? I have not declared it anywhere (this code is all that is related to sounds), because I have not seen it mentioned anywhere.

The file beep1.wav is located in res/raw (I created the folder manually and pasted the file there).

EDIT: the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound_btn);
        final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This generally happens when you create many instances of MediaPlayer in an activity and run out of memory. Can you paste the complete source code to see more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with available space on the phone (I included two sound files, one of them was large (5MB) and after deleting it, the sound plays fine).